# add a notification at a certain time when a checkboxpreference is true

Tags: android, android-notifications

hi I have a checkboxpreference while it's true I need to add a notification which means each day I need to check it it's true if it is I need to add a notification if it's not true I need to delete the notifications added if there is any how can I do that?

**Edit1**
What I have is

```
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_Reminder)) {

                 bool=prefs.getBoolean(key, false);
}}
```

and it gets if it's false or true so how can I get it to do while true?...

**Edit2:**
What I need is to make my notification persist (sure with some updates made each day) when the checkbox is true and when it's false need to delete this notification how to do that? I'm really searching for this but I have no idea how can I do it? any help please?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

var notificationsList = new Array();

$("#checkBoxId").change(function(){

```
if($(this).attr('checked') == true){
    notificationsList.push("Add Notification");  // Add your notification & use it as your need
}else{
    notificationsList = [];   // clear all notifications added
}
```

});